# Unable to Merge dataset into a long format?

Tags: r

I have two separate datasets that I want to merge.
Here is the first one (drug users):

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID_druguser = c("123", "234", "324", "345"), Test_Result = c("POSITIVE", 
"NEGATIVE", "NEGATIVE", "NEGATIVE"), Year_of_Birth = c("1931", 
"1932", "1932", "1932")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Here is the second one (non-drug users):

```
> dput(df2)
structure(list(ID_NONdruguser = c("955", "567", "856", "866"), 
    Test_Result = c("NEGATIVE", "NEGATIVE", "NEGATIVE", "POSITIVE"
    ), Year_of_Birth = c("1932", "1932", "1932", "1932")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I want to combine the two datasets and make it into a long format, like this:

```
> dput(df_final)
structure(list(ID = c("123", "234", "324", "345", "955", "567", 
"856", "866"), Drug_status = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
"No", "No", "No"), Test_Result = c("POSITIVE", "NEGATIVE", "NEGATIVE", 
"NEGATIVE", "NEGATIVE", "NEGATIVE", "NEGATIVE", "POSITIVE"), 
    Year_of_Birth = c("1931", "1932", "1932", "1932", "1932", 
    "1932", "1932", "1932")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

The key with `df_final` is that I want a column indicating if the user was on a drug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `rename` to 'ID' and create a new column and then `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    rename(ID= ID_druguser) %>%
    mutate( Drug_status = 'Yes', .after = ID) %>%
   bind_rows( df2 %>% 
    rename(ID= ID_NONdruguser) %>% 
    mutate(Drug_status = 'No'))
```

-output

```
  ID Drug_status Test_Result Year_of_Birth
1 123         Yes    POSITIVE          1931
2 234         Yes    NEGATIVE          1932
3 324         Yes    NEGATIVE          1932
4 345         Yes    NEGATIVE          1932
5 955          No    NEGATIVE          1932
6 567          No    NEGATIVE          1932
7 856          No    NEGATIVE          1932
8 866          No    POSITIVE          1932
```